# java changing value in for loop

Tags: java

I tested my algorithm in python and it does exactly what I want it to do. Now I just want to write the same code in java. I am running into two issues. One with line 7 and one with line 8. I would like to know why i is not detected even though I have int i inside the for loop. I am taking Java next semester, so sorry if this is a really easy bug to deal with.

```
 public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[] a = {1, 0, 12, 11};
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i:a); {
        if (max <  i); {
            max =  i;
        }
    }
System.out.print("max"); // if method is void, then cannot return value   
    }
 }
```

Comment: You have something extra here `for (int i : a); {` and `if (max <  i); {`

Comment: Your for-loop does nothing. If you look closely, you see you wrote `for (int i : a);`. That's all it does. Remove the semicolumn ;)

Comment: Just a note, this can also be done using `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(a));`

Comment: Oh thanks! A general question to those professional programmers:is the difference between computer engineer and computer science the reason I am asked to write programs that make me build built-in functions? In UC Berkeley, we have computer science (and it is common to ask us how to build built-in functions), not computer engineer and I am just wondering if this is a small example of the difference between the majors.

Comment: No, the reason you are being asked is so that you understand the concept of how it is done. It is also helpful in the learning process of programming. There may be Collections.sort(), but at some point in your education you WILL be asked to implement your own sorting functions, such as bubble sort, insertion sort, and some more advanced sorting techniques that involve divide and conquer algorithms for example.

Comment: for the difference of the two majors, see http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/undergrad/academics/degrees/cs-vs-cen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the trailing semi-colons from the `for` and `if` statements which are terminating those statements

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write your code to make it work. As others have pointed out, be careful with where you put your semi colons.

```
int[] a = { 1, 0, 12, 11 };
int max = a[0];
for (int i : a) {
    if (i > max) {
        max = i;
    }
}
System.out.print(max);
```

Comment: "it looks like you've actually written a min function." How is their logic returning the min?